# CakePhp take time to execute the restfull web services

Tags: rest, cakephp

I have one problem. I have two cake php installations: one for Web Services and another for Web. When I use request handler in Web Services Setup and make Restfull Web Services. After that when we hit this web services using iphone OR using Php ( Curl ) it takes 30 sec time to execute the query. But when I simple put my query in Web Setup it takes 1 second.

I dont know why it take too much time to execute the query in request handler.

Comment: Could you show the code of request, please?

Answer (score 1):

Restfull Web Services may get long time to respond. It is better to calculate time for web service response.

If it is more than 30 seconds, then increase max execution time by using

> ini_set('max_execution_time', $time_limit);

Otherwise, optimize your code.